# Go: Package Function Interface for Local Struct

Tags: go

I have a tricky issue which I'm not sure is possible with Go, basically I'm writing a package that implements a simple binary search, which I want to return a value of a struct which is defined by the user, i.e. not in the package.

So effectively I want a function in the package which can be assigned to a struct that is defined locally, that is to say in `package main`.

So in the package is the function for binary search:

```
package binsearch
func (f *SomeStruct) Get(lookup uint) (int, uint, bool) {
    min := 0
    max := len(f.Key)-1
    at := max/2
    for {
        current := f.Key[at]
        if lookup<current {
            max = at-1
        } else {
        if lookup>current {
            min = at+1
            } else {
                return at, f.Value[at], true // found
            }
        }
        if min>max {
            return 0, 0, false // doesn't exist
        }
        at = (max+min)/2
    }
}
```

And then in main something like:

```
package main

type mystruct struct {
Key []uint
Value []uint
}

func main() {
test := new(mystruct)
// Then add some data here
i, value, ok := test.Get(12345)
}
```

Somehow I need to define in `package main` that the `binsearch.Get` function should be applied to `mystruct`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what it would look like using interfaces:

```
package binsearch

type Searchable interface {
    Key(pos int) uint
    Value(pos int) uint
    Len() int
}

func Get(s Searchable, lookup uint) (int, uint, bool) {
    min := 0
    max := s.Len()-1
    at := max/2
    for {
        current := s.Key(at)
        if lookup<current {
            max = at-1
        } else {
        if lookup>current {
            min = at+1
            } else {
                return at, f.Value(at), true // found
            }
        }
        if min>max {
            return 0, 0, false // doesn't exist
        }
        at = (max+min)/2
    }
}
```

and main

```
package main

import (
    "path/to/binsearch"
)

type mystruct struct {
    key []uint
    value []uint
}

func (m *mystruct) Key(pos int) uint {
    return m.key[pos]
}

func (m *mystruct) Value(pos int) uint {
    return m.value[pos]
}

func (m *mystruct) Len() int {
    return len(m.key)
}

func main() {
    test := new(mystruct)
    // Then add some data here
    i, value, ok := binsearch.Get(test, 12345)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you will have to use an interface and define it on your `mystruct`.

```
type BinarySearchable interface {
    Keys() []uint
    Values() []uint
}

func Get(bs BinarySearchable, lookup uint) (int, uint, bool) {
    keys := bs.Keys()
    vals := bs.Values()
    min := 0
    max := len(keys) - 1
    at := max / 2
    for {
        current := keys[at]
        if lookup < current {
            max = at - 1
        } else {
            if lookup > current {
                min = at + 1
            } else {
                return at, vals[at], true // found
            }
        }
        if min > max {
            return 0, 0, false // doesn't exist
        }
        at = (max + min) / 2
    }
}

type mystruct struct {
    keys   []uint
    values []uint
}

func (ms *mystruct) Keys() []uint {
    return ms.keys
}

func (ms *mystruct) Values() []uint {
    return ms.values
}

func main() {
    test := &mystruct{[]uint{12, 123456, 13}, []uint{1,2,3}}
    fmt.Println(Get(test, 123456))
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/KzSkA1hmjB)

Comment: Well I did expect it would require an interface... but how to do that with an interface?

Comment: @Alasdair I added an example.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have no idea what this is supposed to do. You have an interface which defines two functions that don't exist and no mention of the struct.

Comment: Did you check the playground link?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without interfaces but you have to convert your mystruct type into a binsearch.SomeStruct type. This is because the binsearch.Get function is defined to take a pointer to a binsearch.SomeStruct as a receiver and Go doesn't autconvert types for you in this situation.

There is no general way to do this, but one specific to your application might look like this:

```
s := &SomeStruct{}
copy(test.Key, s.Key)
copy(test.Value, s.Value)

i, value, ok := s.Get(12345)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in the way you described. What Golang use is the concept of interface: you define a set of methods that a given struct must implement.

```
type Fooer interface {
    Bar(i int)
}
```

You can then define a function or method that will take a variable of this type as parameter, and use the defined set of methods to do its job.

```
func Foo(a Fooer) {
    // Do you stuff here using the Bar() method
}
```

The convention is to give the interface a name ending in `-er`. You can see examples of interfaces in the `fmt` package with `Stringer` and `Scanner`, or closer to you example, in the package `sort` which define an interface named `Interface` (which full name is `sort.Interface`, which is a break in the convention but actually cleaner than said convention given there is only one interface in the package and the package is built to work with this interface).

Comment: Thanks but that does not answer my question. This I know already.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the concept of interface. The `binarysearch` package define an interface, and the end-user package (`main`) have to define a struct that will have the method required by the interface. The rest is up to you, SO is not here to do the work in your place.

Comment: Get off your high horse. I've spent the last few hours reading every tutorial I can on interfaces and none of them explain how to use them in any practical sense, only how to make dogs go bark and people or robots drive from place to place. They are all simple and useless examples. SO is here exactly for times like this when I have read everything and am sitting here with no one else to ask wasting hours of time trying to solve what should be a simple problem.

Comment: They are simple and useless examples made to help you understand the mechanism, in a very practical sense. That's not real-life code, but where did you see a tutorial with such code ? More, I pointed you to a most useful example (the `sort` package), which is close to what you need. So yes, I didn't handed you your problem solved like metakeul did, but do you really think you will learn anything that way in the long term ?